# How is navigation effect achieved in playgroundinc.com

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, web-deployment

If you'll go to [playgroundinc.com](http://playgroundinc.com/) you'll be greeted by a beautiful website. Then on top there is a navigation bar which is always there i.e. it seems that it is not reloading with each link click. Even if it is reloading again and again with each link click it just looks like that it is not.

Looking at the source code it just looks like regular navigation in header of the html page. I am just curious as to how one could achieve similar effect.

Comment: it looks like they're using `ajax` to pull in the corresponding page

Comment: That is what I thought, they might be requesting next page using JS and displaying it. But then url in address bar should not change if they are using this method.

Comment: Right, but they could be updating it via JS

Answer (score -2):

You can use the plugin `skrollr`

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/blob/master/src/skrollr.js

Go to the page above, copy the large code displayed, paste it in your text editor and save it as scrollr.js. Add this file in your website folder.

Now go to your index.html (I assume you called it that) and add this code at the bottom of your body:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var s = skrollr.init();
</script>
```

Now you can play with the navigationbar:

```
<div id="nav" data-start="opacity:1;" data-10="opacity:0;">
```

Now if you scroll 4px down, your navigation bar will be invisible.